# O365 Tasks and Flagged emails

Tags: office365, office365-restapi, microsoft-graph-api

I am having a problem accessing more specifically flagged emails.

I was hoping the GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/tasks endpoint would help but right now it doesnt seem to be working.

When talking directly to the messages end point the flag/follow up property is not available and the hasflag:true search paramater does not seem to be working either.

Not sure if there is anyway to get this working currently.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  We don't currently support returning info on flags for messages.  We are in the process of adding support for this feature and this will be available soon.